# Stop the Android softkeyboard from word completion

Tags: android

How do you stop the Android softkeyboard from displaying completed text in a TextView.  It is very important for my application that the spelling is not shown.  In 1.6 SDK I made the InputType = VisiblePassword and that seemed to stop it, however this does not appear to work in the 2.1 SDK.

thanks

Comment: Just to clarify are you trying to hide the text that is in the EditText box?  Or are you trying to hide the auto suggest text at the top of the soft keyboard area?

Comment: I am trying to hide the auto suggest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try setting inputType to textNoSuggestions? That's API an API level 5, though, so you probably want to continue to include textVisiblePassword for the previous versions.

Comment: I can't find textNoSuggestions in the eclipse XML editor.  Do you know why this is?

Comment: I added it manually
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword|textNoSuggestions"

but then I get an error message for a malformed xml file :(

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="4"/>

Comment: So I assume I will need to change the minSdkVersion to 5, but then 1.6 users will not be able to use the product!

Comment: No, change targetSdkVersion to 5 and minSdkVersion to whatever level you want to support.

Comment: OK that makes sense, I will give it a try tonight

Comment: ahhh, still not working.  I made the targetSdkVersion to 5 but textNoSuggestions is still not visible in Eclipse...I restarted eclipse also after making the change.

Comment: Looks like you need to set the target from the project properties. Select the Project, then File > Properties. Go to Android. Set the target there.

Comment: That's assuming you're using Eclipse.

Comment: you would not believe it...it still does not work.

I have everything setup with textNoSuggestions and visiblePassword.  It compiles and runs fine, however, when I run it in the emulator I get the same problem...suggestions are showing.  It seems that the soft keyboard simply ignores the flat????

Answer (score 1):

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

according to [this](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.devel/143278), may or may not be supported by the IDE.

However, this seems to work more often

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
```